# How to get the "periodic restart recycle value" of an IIS Application Pool using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

I am using Powershell 5.0.10586.117 with an IIS 7.5.

When running

```
Get-ItemProperty ($singleAppPool) -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

I receive i.e.

```
DefaultAppPool
value          : 03:00:00
Attributes     : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute}
ChildElements  : {}
ElementTagName : add
Methods        : 
Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

However I only want to get the *value*. But

```
Get-ItemProperty ($singleAppPool) -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection
```

fails with a "not found" error message.

How to be able to get *value* only here?

For the sake of being able to reproduce use

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If the command works per your example, you can get the value property like this:

```
(Get-ItemProperty ($singleAppPool) -Name Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection).Value
```

I can't diagnose why you get a "not found" error message without you sharing the error or without knowing what is in $singleAppPool or if that is a valid item on your server.